# Generate css code after defined pattern with javascript or less

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, less

Is there a way to "generate" code following a pattern that I specify?
Maybe a website, some "trick" in excel or some programming language (that I probably don't know)?

My css is the following:

```css
.start-row-m-1.row-m-4 {
     height: calc(100vw - 15px);
     top: 0;
}
 .start-row-m-1.row-m-2 {
     height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
     top: 0;
}
 .start-row-m-1.row-m-1 {
     height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
     top: 0;
}
 .start-row-m-2.row-m-4 {
     height: calc(100vw - 15px);
     top: calc(0.5 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
 .start-row-m-2.row-m-2 {
     height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
     top: calc(0.5 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
 .start-row-m-2.row-m-1 {
     height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
     top: calc(0.5 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
 .start-row-m-3.row-m-4 {
     height: calc(100vw - 15px);
     top: calc(1 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
 .start-row-m-3.row-m-2 {
     height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
     top: calc(1 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
 .start-row-m-3.row-m-1 {
     height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
     top: calc(1 * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
```

I think that is enough that you get the idea.

I have 3 code segments for every row and everything is changing are some small numbers.

The pseudo code I imagine would be something like this:

.start-row-m-2 **+1**.row-m-4 {
height: calc(100vw - 15px);
top: calc(0.5 **+0.5** * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
.start-row-m-2 **+1**.row-m-2 {
height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
top: calc(0.5 **+0.5** * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
.start-row-m-2 **+1**.row-m-1 {
height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
top: calc(0.5 **+0.5** * (50vw - 7.5px));
}

Basically every three "blocks" increment the first number (my class) +1 and add 0.5 to my calc.
So far I just manually did this by hand for around 40 rows but I need a lot more for different viewports.

My original css is written in less, maybe there is something build into less that can help me?

I hope the tags are appropriate. Because I don't know how to achieve this I tagged some stuff I could imagine it can work with.

Comment: You may be looking for a CSS preprocessor like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: @XyRen Isn't less a preprocessor?

Comment: sorry didn't see that. afaik less does not have good looping facility like Sass's `@for`, `@while` etc.

Comment: @XyRen But still thank you! Loop is a good keyword to search for a less solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with LESS:

```
.loop (@i, @n) when (@i < 40)
{
  .start-row-m-@{i}.row-m-4 {
  height: calc(100vw - 15px);
    top: calc( @n * (50vw - 7.5px));
  }
  .start-row-m-@{i}.row-m-2 {
  height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
  top: calc(@n * (50vw - 7.5px));
  }
  .start-row-m-@{i}.row-m-1 {
  height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
  top: calc(@n * (50vw - 7.5px));
  }
  .loop(@i + 1, @i * 0.5)
}
.loop(1, 0);
```

Or javascript:

```js
let css = "";
for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
  css += `.start-row-m-${i + 1}.row-m-4 {
  height: calc(100vw - 15px);
  top: calc(${i * 0.5} * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
.start-row-m-${i + 1}.row-m-2 {
  height: calc(50vw - 7.5px);
  top: calc(${i * 0.5} * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
.start-row-m-${i + 1}.row-m-1 {
  height: calc(25vw - 3.75px);
  top: calc(${i * 0.5} * (50vw - 7.5px));
}
`;
}
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = css;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also did a less version myself. But the only problem with it, and also yours (you couldn't know it). Row 1 is somewhat special and the rule doesn't fit for it. How can I make it to start at `.start-row-m-2` instead of `.start-row-m-1`. I tried `.start-row-m-@{i} + 1` but thats not working.

Comment: you start it with the `.loop(2, 1)` and simply add manually the "special" row